# What error would this function cause if its placed in a generic library?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

```
int foo(char *p)
{
static int i = 0; 
if (*p == '\0') return i;
i++;
return foo(p+1);
}
```

What would be the problem if this function was placed in a generic library. How can I modify the code to sidestep the problem?
If this code were to be placed in a generic library will it return the correct string length?

Comment: Why are you asking this?

Comment: I hope this code is never placed in any library. It is not thread-safe, doesn't check or assert on `NULL`, behaves weird with multiple calls and is just plain inefficient.

Comment: I guess this is just a random homework question. And a bad question even.

Comment: If you don't know what a generic library is, then you obviously aren't putting this code into a generic library, so the question is moot. It's like asking, "What if I drink this before riding my unicycle?" when you don't know how to ride a unicycle.

Comment: Hi Raymond. You're my hero.

Comment: What amazes me is that the more I read this, the more I conclude that this IS a homework question, crafted by a boneheaded professor. How much bad teachers there are in the world...

Comment: Seems like a fairly reasonable homework question to me, to teach what `static` local variables are. If "what is a generic library in C" really is part of the assignment (rather than being added by the questioner) then I expect it's just checking that the student understands a term used in lectures or other supporting material.

Answer (score 2):

One problem would be that the state persists between calls:

```
foo("hello");
foo("world");
```

The second call would return the incorrect result because `i` is not reset.

Answer (score 2):

If you call it twice in succession, `i` won't be what you expect. That's because it's initialised at startup and retains its previous value across calls.

In addition, it won't work well with threads, and the idea of recursion is best used when the "search space" reduces quickly, like a binary search halving the space at each recursion level.

Processing a string character by character with recursion is a bone-headed idea, since you only reduce the search space by one character at a time.